# Getting a data from a page to another (specifically id) on my table using column render of datatables. Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I would like to get the data of a specific row in my datatables and display it in another page where I edit the contents of the table. I have no idea how to do that. Here is my Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var table;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#table').DataTable({
      "responsive": true,
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [],
      "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('Infoserbilis/ajax_list')?>",
        "type": "POST"
      },
      "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [13], //first column / numbering column
        "orderable": false,
        "data": "download_link",
        "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
          return '<a href="update_content/' + row.id + '">Edit</a>';
        }, //set not orderable
      }, ],

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to explain your question a bit more...tell us what you want to achieve: another query? filtering your query? etc?, Anything to figure out what you want to do will help

Comment: https://codepen.io/postor/pen/RxZeVK  https://codepen.io/postor/pen/goxBWR something like this?

Comment: How about using [DataTables Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html)?